# Changes in the source file(.wxs) to get a custom install

Tags: xml, wix, wix3.5

I have a radiobutton on a dialog box (i have created my own dialog box),(i m running as an admin)

```
-All Admins
```

My Current Work:
     Once i select this radiobutton(All Admins),click on next the system must check for the admin rights/logged in as administrators.

If yes it should install for all the admins and if not it should generate an error dialog.

I now know how to generate dialogs (it was confusing too at the beginning).

Also the current msi that i have installs for admins and i am not able to install for users , let me know how do i correct that too.

Please help at the earliest as i do not know how to proceed with it.

Thanks

Eddie

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. What is your actual problem?

WiX generates Windows Installer packages, and Windows Installer has only two modes:

- *for all users*, or
- *for the current user*.

No application can be installed for *All* Administrators. What if another administrator account is created? What if a limited user account is given administrator privileges? The situation gets even trickier if you consider domain users.

So in your case, All Admins corresponds to *all users*. If the app is supposed to be run by administrators only, it is the app responsibility to show (regular) user an error message and exit. In Vista+, it must also have the appropriate manifest requesting administrator privileges, so that it's UAC-compatible.

Read [Single Package Authoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408068.aspx) article for more information on how to create a package which can be installed in either *per-machine* or *per-user* mode. This functionality is available with **Windows Installer 5.0**, i.e. starting with **Windows 7** and **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

Comment: I want to run the installer package both a s admin and as a standard user , however the difference i want to include is i want to install only for the admins present in a system and not for the standard users , is there any way i can write the <Publish Property="ALLUSERS" Value="something different that only installs for all the admins">, thanks for the answer i appreciate this help

Comment: Or can you please let me know how do i check for the admin rights is a user posses on selection of a radiobutton and clicking next i have been trying :
 <Fragment>
  <PropertyRef Id="INSTALLPREFA" />
   <Condition Message="!(loc.Administrator)"><![CDATA[INSTALLPREFA = "Admin"]]>
   </Condition>
in a custom dialog box i have created

Comment: @eddie As I already said there are only two possibilities: *per-user* (installs for currently logged-on user) and *per-machine* (installs for all users). You can't install for all administrator users only; even if you use something different than Windows Installer. (Of course, you can enumerate all user accounts, and add the shortcut to your app to their profile but this approach won't work with roaming profiles, and after all it's error-prone.) I can't still imagine a use-case for all-admin installation though.

Comment: @eddie You would use [`Privileged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370852) property to condition per-machine installation. Don't forget to test the package for UAC compliance under Vista+. Read [Guidelines for Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368772) to get more info.